# Aptanta 3 on Ubuntu - How to tell if 32 or 64 bit version

Tags: version, aptana, 32bit-64bit

I am using aptana 3 on ubuntu.  I am using 64 bit ubuntu in virtual box on a mac pro.  How can I tell if I am using the 32 or 64 bit version of aptana?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Painfully stupid way: go into the ini file and try and tell it it can have 4GBs of RAM. If you are on 32 bit, when you try to start it again, it will say failure to launch vm.